# Laravel Validation with Soft Deleted Model and Unique DB field

Tags: database, laravel, validation

I am trying to wrap my head around how to handle this use case.

I have a user model that has a unique db field (email). I am also using soft deletes.

I need to handle three cases:

1) The user model is updated. At the moment my validation stops the user from being updated, because ofcourse this email already exists. I think this is easily solved by ignoring the email validation if the email has not been changed.

2) A different user model is updated and the email is changed to another email already present in the db.

3) A new model is created and the email is already present in the db.

All the above scenarios must also take into account soft deleted models.

Would someone have some advice on how to structure this?

Comment: I guess you will craft yourself 3 different [FormRequests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests) and maybe introduce some custom rules. Thats what I would do.

Comment: I have this all handled in Laravel controller public methods store and update. The form is just one form that sends all the data.With regards to updates, the form fields are prefilled with existing values for that user from the DB.

Comment: Yea move that to FormRequests, it will help you thin out the controllers, thats what I'd do. **Note**: the update FR should have some kind of logic in the `rules()` to switch between updating self & someone else. And obviously you do not need 3 FR but 2, my bad. Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a plan, I will look into FormRequests. Thank you!

Comment: When you are done, post the **update** FR here since thats going to be the most problematic one and I will help you out even further, with actual code (if you do not figure it out yourself in the meantime). Also I name FRs like: `UserUpdateRequest`, `ModelActionRequest` or `ModelAction` and of course use `art make:request` command.

Comment: Okay I understand FormRequests now, but I fail to see how my situation has changed. I know my controllers are much cleaner now but I now have additional problems. For example the validated request is returned as an array instead of an object, so my logic to create a model ($user->email = $validated->email) doesn't work of course and I know how to dig into the array to get the value. Fine for simple string or integers but I also have arrays of data (roles/permissions) in the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179842/discussion-between-piotr-g-and-kyslik).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Rule::unique()` validation.  Either get your user model out from the route if your using model binding, or do a traditional db query to get the user out by an ID (if your passing one in). Then you can do this in the validation.

This should accommodate soft deleted models too.

```
return [
    'email' => Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($user->email)->whereNull('deleted_at')->orWhereNotNull('deleted_at')
]
```

Comment: In Laravel 7.0 using `->withTrashed` as in your second example fails with: `ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique::withTrashed()`

Answer (score 9):

For updating you can adjust your validation rules to ignore the *current user record* when updating. The rule signature is this:

`'email' => 'unique:user,email,{$userId},id,deleted_at,NULL'`

For inserting new, a rule like this:

`'email' => 'unique:user,email,NULL,NULL,deleted_at,NULL'`

Should work and ignore `softDeleted` records. If will still fail if you have a unique key on your database.

Of course, if you also undelete a record, you will have duplicates, which Laravel can not prevent.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all the answers I received. As I can only mark one as correct I will be fair and mark the first one.

Comment: No worries. Using `Rule` is better/more versatile anyway. I'm just used to using straight strings. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 8 it is greatly simplified using `withoutTrashed()` rule modifier:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'email' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    Rule::unique('users', 'email')->withoutTrashed()
]
```

The method is mentioned in the L8 API:

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.html#method_withoutTrashed

---

Is it probably also worth mentioning that there is a `Rule::exists()->withoutTrashed()` available as well mentioned in the L8 API too:

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Exists.html#method_withoutTrashed

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 8, the above solutions doesn't work anymore, probably the unique rule was changed down the road.

However, you can go with the following validation rule.

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

'email' => [
    'required',
    'email',
    Rule::unique('users', 'email')->where(function($query){
       return $query->whereNull('deleted_at')
         ->orWhereNotNull('deleted_at');
    })
]
```